# Functoriality and inverse images of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

I'm now learning sheaf theory from Gortz and Wedhorn's *Algbraic Geometry 1 - Schemes* and trying to understand the direct image and the inverse image of sheaves.

In the book, the authors said that

> ...... Again the construction of $f^{+}\mathcal{G}$ and hence of $f^{-1} \mathcal{G}$ is functorial in $\mathcal{G}$. Therefore we obtain a functor $f^{-1}$ from the category of presheaves on $Y$ to the category of sheaves on $X$.......

Now let me clarify the notations. In the quoted sentences, $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map and $\mathcal{G}$ is a presheaf of $Y$. A presheaf on $X$ is defined by
$$
U \mapsto \mathrm{colim}_{V \supset f(U), V \subset Y \,  \text{open}}  \mathcal{G}(V)
$$
and the restriction maps are induced by the restriction maps of $\mathcal{G}$. We denote this presheaf by $f^{+}\mathcal{G}$, and the sheafification of it by $f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$. This is the inverse image of $\mathcal{G}$ under $f$.

My question is: What does the word "**functorial**" mean in the quoted sentences?

I have looked up the book *Categories for the Working Mathematician* by Mac Lane, and only find the definition of **natural** when discussing natural transformations. It seems that this is the same as the word **functorial**? Actually I'm lost in checking from the definition and finding what I need to verify (to show that **$f^{-1} \mathcal{G}$ is functorial in $\mathcal{G}$**).

I've read the question and answers on [What exactly is functoriality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922113/what-exactly-is-functoriality) but still feeling hard to find out what to check.

Thank you for your helps!

Comment: Once you get comfortable with the notion of categories, you will see that an assignment is "functorial" if it also induces morphisms in a consistent way. In you case, the inverse image of a sheaf gives a new sheaf, but that is only the first part of being a functor. The other part is that, given a morphism of sheaves, there is a morphism between the respective direct images of the sheaves (in one or the other direction). This is the (or a) meaning of being functorial.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already know what a presheaf is, it may be convenient for you to see why a presheaf is a functor. Basically it amounts to the existence of restriction maps and certain conditions on them.

Take a presheaf of sets $F$ on your topological space $X$.
The condition of being a presheaf is that:

- For any open set $U$ you get a set $FU$.
- Given open sets $U\subseteq V$ you obtain a restriction function $\rho^V_U:FV\to FU$.
- For any open $U$, the restriction map $\rho^U_U$ is the identity function on $FU$.
- For open sets $U\subseteq V\subseteq W$ you have $\rho^W_U=\rho^V_U\circ\rho^W_V$.

These four conditions are exactly the conditions that "$FU$ is functorial on the open sets $U$".
Writing $i^U_V:U\to V$ for the inclusion of $U$ into $V$, one could denote the corresponding restriction function as $\rho^V_U=F(i^U_V)$.
Denoting the category of open sets of $X$ by $\text{Top}_X$ and the category of sets by $\text{Set}$, then $F$ is a functor $F:\text{Top}_X^{\text{op}}\to\text{Set}$. ($\text{op}$ because $\rho^V_U=F(i^U_V)$ goes "in the opposite direction" as $i^U_V$).

If you denote the categories of sheaves on $X$ and $Y$ by $\text{Sh}X$ and $\text{Sh}Y$, respectively, then for any continuous function $f:X\to Y$ you obtain a functor $f^{-1}:\text{Sh}Y\to\text{Sh}X$. Explicitly, this means that

- For any sheaf $G$ on $Y$ you get a sheaf $f^{-1}G$ on $X$.
- Given a morphism $\alpha:F\to G$ of sheaves on $Y$, you obtain a morphism $f^{-1}\alpha:f^{-1}F\to f^{-1}G$ of sheaves on $X$. (Note that here $f^{-1}\alpha$ goes "in the same direction" as $\alpha$).
- For any sheaf $G$ on $Y$, the morphism $f^{-1}(\text{id}_G):f^{-1}G\to f^{-1}G$ is the identity morphism on $f^{-1}G$.
- For morphisms $F\xrightarrow{\alpha} G\xrightarrow{\beta} H$ of sheaves on $Y$ you have $f^{-1}(\beta\circ\alpha)=(f^{-1}\beta)\circ(f^{-1}\alpha)$.

So you need to check the last 3 conditions on $f^{-1}$.

Comment: A good answer. Two small typos: "Explicitely" should be "Explicitly", and "For any sheaf $G$ on $Y$ you get a set $f^{-1}G$ on $X$" should be "For any sheaf ... you get a **sheaf**...".

Comment: @KReiser The first one is not a typo, I just learned that I've been writing it wrong all the time haha. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for the feedback, and I suppose the upvote is yours as well. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that I have misunderstood the notions of **naturality** and **functorality**. Is this right that actually the two notions have nothing to do with each other?

Comment: @HetongXu You're welcome. Do you know the definition of a morphism of sheaves? It's a collection of morphisms satisfying a commutative diagram for every inclusion of open sets. The commutativity of those diagrams is the naturality condition.

Comment: Aha, I got it! I have mixed up all these stuffs before. Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Good to be helpful. Cheers.